# mongodb findOne not found document in base

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

in my collection i have this document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eecb84a9e41ff609fd6389a"),
    "uid" : NumberLong(619942065802969109),
    "banmute" : 0,
    "expire" : ISODate("2023-03-15T13:06:18.694Z"),
    "fid" : "3cac4490b6ca491e838d4e5317e5b87e",
    "id" : null,
    "nick" : "Flawe",
    "nicks_ld" : "",
    "old_nicks" : "",
    "reason" : ""
}
```

Indexes is:

```
/* 1 */
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "fsl.index_profile"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "uid" : 1
        },
        "name" : "uid_1",
        "ns" : "fsl.index_profile",
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

On direct request i have null answer:

```
db.getCollection('index_profile').findOne({uid: 619942065802969109})
result: ->
null
```

But if i request $gte i found it:

```
db.getCollection('index_profile').find({uid: {$gte: 619942065802969109}}).limit(1)
result: ->
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eecb84a9e41ff609fd6389a"),
    "uid" : NumberLong(619942065802969109),
    "banmute" : 0,
    "expire" : ISODate("2023-03-15T13:06:18.694Z"),
    "fid" : "3cac4490b6ca491e838d4e5317e5b87e",
    "id" : null,
    "nick" : "Flawe",
    "nicks_ld" : "",
    "old_nicks" : "",
    "reason" : ""
}
```

I tried deleting the cache, rebooting the server, deleting indexes, assigned different new indexes

I am in despair, help solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried:

```
db.getCollection('index_profile').findOne({uid: NumberLong(619942065802969109)})
```